Scroll speed on any column or row (lazy or not lazy) is slow or limited (iOS Kotlin multiplatform)
I use Kotlin Multiplatform. When using any element with scroll, the scrolling in iOS is slow or it doesn't continue scrolling after the gesture — similar to scrolling with a mouse on PC. On Android, the scroll is good/normal (fast and continues scrolling after the gesture). It's not a matter of optimization.
You can see videos at this link:
mega
This is my code:
LazyHorizontalGrid(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(60.dp)
                ,
                rows = GridCells.Fixed(1),
                state = gridState,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
            ) {
                viewModel.state.planProxyList?.let {
                    items(it) { planItem ->
                        PlanHomePreviewCard(
                            plan = planItem,
                            onClick = {
                                println(planItem.name)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

PlanHomePreviewCard is a light element, so it's not a matter of optimization.
The scroll in iOS becomes normal in Kotlin multiplatform.
